How to Display an Image Only on the First Page Using @react-pdf/renderer?
I'm working on a PDF generation feature using the @react-pdf/renderer package in my React application. I need to display an image only on the first page of the PDF. Below is the relevant portion of my code:

import { Document, Page, Text, View, StyleSheet, pdf, Image } from '@react-pdf/renderer'
import moment from 'moment'
import { headerImgPdfQuote } from '../../../Clients/devisTemplate'

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  page: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    padding: '0 40px'
  },
  header: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0
  },
  headerImage: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 'auto'
  }
})

const QuotePDF = () => (
  <Document>
    <Page size="A4" style={styles.page} wrap>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <View render={({ pageNumber }) => (
          pageNumber === 1 && (
            <Image src={headerImgPdfQuote} style={styles.headerImage} />
          )
        )} />
        <View render={({ pageNumber }) => (
          pageNumber === 1 && (
            <Text>Reference: {quoteData.ref}</Text>
          )
        )} />
        <View render={({ pageNumber }) => (
          pageNumber === 1 && (
            <Text>{moment(quoteData.createdAt).format('DD/MM/YYYY')}</Text>
          )
        )} />
      </View>
      <Text render={({ pageNumber, totalPages }) => `${pageNumber}/${totalPages}`} fixed />
    </Page>
  </Document>
)

const generatePDF = async () => {
  const blob = await pdf(<QuotePDF />).toBlob()
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  const link = document.createElement('a')
  link.href = url
  link.download = `quote_${moment(quoteData.createdAt).format('DD_MM_YYYY')}.pdf`
  link.click()
}


The headerImgPdfQuote is a base64 encoded image. I converted an image to base64 and stored it in a variable which I then exported and imported here.
The image and some text should only appear on the first page. However, the image does not appear at all. What am I doing wrong, and how can I ensure the image displays only on the first page?
What did you try?
I tried using the render prop to conditionally render the Image component based on the page number. Specifically, I used render={({ pageNumber }) => (pageNumber === 1 && )} to attempt to display the image only on the first page.
What were you expecting?
I expected the image to appear only on the first page of the generated PDF, but it does not appear at all.
What am I doing wrong, and how can I ensure the image displays only on the first page?

The docs on the package's NPM page and on GitHub leave a lot to desire, but I managed to find this page with more elaborate documentation and even there they didn't state whether they start pagination from 0 or from 1. They start from 1 - I checked by running some export in my own project - so this is not the issue. Does the text work?

About Image source:
I think @react-pdf/renderer are unable to display base64 encoded image. It needs proper prefix before the base64 encoded string.
Here is an example:
Suppose you base64 image =

iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAA...

and your image format is png. Then your image source string should like:

data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAA...

We call this representation DataUrl. So you may convert your base64 image to DataUrl by adding proper prefix.
Code example:


const base64ImageString = "your base64 encoded string";
const DataUrl = `data:image/png;base64,${base64ImageString}`;



Now use the DataUrl as your Image source.

<Image src={DataUrl }  />

Now it should work as expected.
About image and pagination:
If you want to put your image in the first page, then simply write the <Image /> tag. It wouldn't bring your image to next page. It will print the image to pdf once at the first page.You don't have to use render={({ pageNumber }) => (pageNumber === 1 && <Image />)}.
But if you want an image or any other element to bring to the every page, then you have to use fixed property on the element like <Image src="/example.png" fixed/>
Finally your code should be:


import { Document, Page, Text, View, StyleSheet, pdf, Image } from '@react-pdf/renderer'
import moment from 'moment'
import { headerImgPdfQuote } from '../../../Clients/devisTemplate'

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  page: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    padding: '0 40px'
  },
  header: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0
  },
  headerImage: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 'auto'
  }
})
const imageSrc = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${headerImgPdfQuote}`;

const QuotePDF = () => (
  <Document>
    <Page size="A4" style={styles.page} wrap>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Image src={imageSrc} style={styles.headerImage} />
        <Text>Reference: {quoteData.ref}</Text>
        <Text>{moment(quoteData.createdAt).format('DD/MM/YYYY')}</Text>
      </View>
      <Text render={({ pageNumber, totalPages }) => `${pageNumber}/${totalPages}`} fixed />
    </Page>
  </Document>
)

const generatePDF = async () => {
  const blob = await pdf(<QuotePDF />).toBlob()
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  const link = document.createElement('a')
  link.href = url
  link.download = `quote_${moment(quoteData.createdAt).format('DD_MM_YYYY')}.pdf`
  link.click()
}




The issue is not with rendering the image itself; the image renders correctly. The problem is ensuring that the image only appears on the first page of the PDF document. I'm using the render prop with a conditional statement to check if pageNumber === 1, but the image still show on all pages. How can I fix this to render the image only on the first page?
